# Is there a way to include a file for everyone in PHP?

Tags: php, include

I have a bunch of vhosts set up on a server and I want a sort of universal include folder that they can all include from. In the php.ini the include_path and open_basedir both include the path to the folder. The include is located in the same path as all the sites and I've even tried setting permissions to 777 and put the files in the same group as everyone, but PHP refuses to include unless they have the same owner. Is there any way to get around this issue and let them include from that folder regardless of the owner?

Comment: This doesn't represent a vote-to-close, but just a thought: this *might* be more directly applicable to [Webmasters Stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can include remote files, read this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Comment: Just an FYI, enabling the remote include can be dangerous, and if you do enable it, make sure you filter any string that is being included (even if it is not meant to be a remote address) as it can lead to an exploit / hacked server if you do not.

Comment: I'm a bit leery of this as the purpose of what I'm doing is including a specialized PHP script to help deduced holes that people might be exploiting to hack us. It's a bit hard to manually traverse each file as we have 80+ sites on this VPS and thousands of files to troll through. I'd rather not make more possible backdoors if possible.

Comment: It's not exactly clean, but you could make a symlink to a common include file on all of the vhosts then set follow symlinks in Apache.  You'll need a new file for every domain, but at least you'll only have to edit one.

Comment: I just tried symlinks a few minutes ago. They only work if the linked file has the same owner as the vhost. I've tried making the symlinks as the vhost user as well and that didn't work either. If in the end there is no decent solution I may just go through each site and give them all a copy of the file.